# How do I check if I can read a document when using ContentResolver to query a DocumentsContract Uri?

Tags: android

I'm using a `DocumentsContract` query to try to speed up reading a folder. I got most data but I'm struggling with the flag that tells me if I can read the document.

This is the query:

```
contentResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_SIZE, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_FLAGS), null, null, null)
```

`DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_FLAGS` has in its documentation:

```
     /**
     * Flags that apply to a document. This column is required.
     * <p>
     * Type: INTEGER (int)
     *
     * @see #FLAG_DIR_BLOCKS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE
     * @see #FLAG_DIR_PREFERS_GRID
     * @see #FLAG_DIR_PREFERS_LAST_MODIFIED
     * @see #FLAG_DIR_SUPPORTS_CREATE
     * @see #FLAG_PARTIAL
     * @see #FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY
     * @see #FLAG_SUPPORTS_DELETE
     * @see #FLAG_SUPPORTS_METADATA
     * @see #FLAG_SUPPORTS_MOVE
     * @see #FLAG_SUPPORTS_REMOVE
     * @see #FLAG_SUPPORTS_RENAME
     * @see #FLAG_SUPPORTS_SETTINGS
     * @see #FLAG_SUPPORTS_THUMBNAIL
     * @see #FLAG_SUPPORTS_WRITE
     * @see #FLAG_VIRTUAL_DOCUMENT
     * @see #FLAG_WEB_LINKABLE
     */
```

I can see `WRITE` there but what about `READ`?

Comment: How did you obtain that uri?

Comment: `DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree()`

Comment: Before that you have already an uri. I asked for that one.

Comment: Oh you get the `Uri` of the parent folder from the file picker, don't know if there are other ways to do that.

Comment: Please be exact. A file picker for a folder?  Which action did you use? Come to the point finally.

Comment: You call `startActivityForResult` passing a `Intent` for `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: Well then in onActivityResult the obtained intent does not only give you an uri but also read write permission flags. You can even take persistant uri permissions on them. So now you have read and write permission for all files in the tree. It is unclear why you wanna check if you can read a document as of course you can.

Comment: In theory you could have a child folder that you don't have permissions to access within that tree that was returned. I'm not sure where the permissions come from but if they map back to the OS file system permissions, then you could even have files that you can't read.

Comment: Well give one example and i believe you. At the moment i believe what i told you.

Answer (score 0):

`val canRead = context.checkCallingUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`

Comment: Does it use an IPC call? Does that return quickly? the entire point of using `ContentResolver` is to do it quickly since I have to iterate a lot of files. Using `DocumentFile` was slow because most methods perform an IPC call.

Comment: What is an IPC call?

Comment: Interprocess communication https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl Basically how different processes talk to each other, super slow.

Comment: You can use it to check the read permission for the folder uri.

Comment: Just tested this and it doesn't appear to be IPC, it returns pretty quickly. I'll use this but really wonder if there is a way to get it out of the flags.

Comment: There is no such flag.